# How to draw a simple chart for windows phone 7

Tags: charts, windows-phone-7.1

I'm looking for a simplest way to display and/or draw a very basic chart on Windows phone (no data points, no axis, just a simple line showing a general trend).

I've tried looking for a charting libraries but all seem very complex (and all I could find were expensive).

Second thing I've tried is to simply draw a line on canvas - but Canvas element in WP7 doesn't seem to allow drawing on it.

Any hints, pointers to tutorials you could give me?

Comment: you could try to create lines or line segments in code behind and add them to your canvas.children with the right start and end coordinates (Top, Left ... properties and alignments) .

Comment: You will need to looking into WriteableBitmap. I would recommend looking at the WriteableBitmapEx library on codeplex http://bit.ly/wzQFPY as it has many useful methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [AM Charts](http://wpf.amcharts.com/quick)

it's free, open-source and fairly easy to use.  Quite a few WP7 developers are using it

Here's a quick example usage:

```
<amq:SerialChart x:Name="_24HoursLineGraph" DataSource="{Binding Data24}" CategoryValueMemberPath="Date" AxisForeground="White" PlotAreaBackground="Black" GridStroke="DarkGray" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20">
         <amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
             <amq:LineGraph ValueMemberPath="Close" Title="Close" Brush="Blue" />
         </amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
</amq:SerialChart>
```